# Direct links to pages in Facebook iFrame application?

Tags: facebook, facebook-iframe

Is it possible to link directly to inner pages in a Facebook iFrame app?

For example, say my app lives at `http://www.example.com/app`.  Can I have a link like `http://apps.facebook.com/my_app/?id=256` which will navigate to somewhere like `http://www.example.com/app/id/256` in my app that lives in the Facebook canvas?

I did a quick search around but didn't find anything, so if there's something already out there, please point me to it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your callback URL is set to `http://fb.domain.com/` and your canvas URL to `http://apps.facebook.com/domain_app/`, navigating to `http://apps.facebook.com/domain_app/hello` will load `http://fb.domain.com/hello`. This holds true for querystring parameters as well.

Comment: Good stuff. A few things to note: 1) the url in the browser will stay http://apps.facebook.com/domain_app/hello while the user is using the app. 2) if the user refreshes the page they will be sent once again to http://fb.domain.com/hello. Currently, what I plan on doing to avoid this, is redirect the parent frame ( the http://apps.facebook.com/domain_app/hello ) back to http://apps.facebook.com/domain_app/ once I capture the /hello parameter in a session. That way, they are sent to http://fb.domain.com/hello and subsequent refreses will send the user to http://fb.domain.com/